# Why does this code not work correctly for all inputs?

Tags: python, quicksort

```
def quicksort(a,l,h):
    if l>=h:
        return
    pivot = a[l]
    i=l+1
    for j in range(l+1,h+1):
        if a[i]<pivot:
            a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
            i+=1
    a[l],a[i-1] = a[i-1],a[l]
    quicksort(a,l,i-2)
    quicksort(a,i,h)


a = [6,7,8,9,5,1,2,3,4]
print 'Before sort',a
quicksort(a,0,len(a)-1)
print 'After sort',a
```

It works for [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] but not for [6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Can't you step through the code and find out for yourself why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written it is not very Pythonic, more akin to how you'd do it in C maybe. Does it need to be an in-place operation? It seems much clearer to do it with return values:

```
def quicksort(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a

    bot = []
    eq = []
    top = []
    pivot = a[0]

    for x in a:
        if x < pivot:
            bot.append(x)
        elif x == pivot:
            eq.append(x)
        else:
            top.append(x)

    return quicksort(bot) + eq + quicksort(top)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to write an in-place implementation.